# K-means incoherent behaviour choosing K with Elbow method, BIC, variance explained and silhouette

Tags: clustering, k-means

I'm trying to cluster some vectors with 90 features with K-means. Since this algorithm asks me the number of clusters, I want to validate my choice with some nice math.
I expect to have from 8 to 10 clusters. The features are Z-score scaled.

**Elbow method and variance explained**

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

K = range(1,50)
KM = [KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(dt_trans) for k in K]
centroids = [k.cluster_centers_ for k in KM]

D_k = [cdist(dt_trans, cent, 'euclidean') for cent in centroids]
cIdx = [np.argmin(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
dist = [np.min(D,axis=1) for D in D_k]
avgWithinSS = [sum(d)/dt_trans.shape[0] for d in dist]

# Total with-in sum of square
wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist]
tss = sum(pdist(dt_trans)**2)/dt_trans.shape[0]
bss = tss-wcss

kIdx = 10-1

# elbow curve
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(K, avgWithinSS, 'b*-')
ax.plot(K[kIdx], avgWithinSS[kIdx], marker='o', markersize=12, 
markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='None')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Average within-cluster sum of squares')
plt.title('Elbow for KMeans clustering')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(K, bss/tss*100, 'b*-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of variance explained')
plt.title('Elbow for KMeans clustering')
```

[image: Elbow method]
[image: Variance]

From these two pictures, it seems that the number of clusters never stops :D. Strange! Where is the elbow? How can I choose K?

**Bayesian information criterion**

This methods comes directly from X-means and uses the [BIC](http://Bayesian%20information%20criterion) to choose the number of clusters. [another ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793532/how-do-i-determine-k-when-using-k-means-clustering)

```
    from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def bic(clusters, centroids):
    num_points = sum(len(cluster) for cluster in clusters)
    num_dims = clusters[0][0].shape[0]
    log_likelihood = _loglikelihood(num_points, num_dims, clusters, centroids)
    num_params = _free_params(len(clusters), num_dims)
    return log_likelihood - num_params / 2.0 * np.log(num_points)


def _free_params(num_clusters, num_dims):
    return num_clusters * (num_dims + 1)


def _loglikelihood(num_points, num_dims, clusters, centroids):
    ll = 0
    for cluster in clusters:
        fRn = len(cluster)
        t1 = fRn * np.log(fRn)
        t2 = fRn * np.log(num_points)
        variance = _cluster_variance(num_points, clusters, centroids) or np.nextafter(0, 1)
        t3 = ((fRn * num_dims) / 2.0) * np.log((2.0 * np.pi) * variance)
        t4 = (fRn - 1.0) / 2.0
        ll += t1 - t2 - t3 - t4
    return ll

def _cluster_variance(num_points, clusters, centroids):
    s = 0
    denom = float(num_points - len(centroids))
    for cluster, centroid in zip(clusters, centroids):
        distances = euclidean_distances(cluster, centroid)
        s += (distances*distances).sum()
    return s / denom

from scipy.spatial import distance
def compute_bic(kmeans,X):
    """
    Computes the BIC metric for a given clusters

    Parameters:
    -----------------------------------------
    kmeans:  List of clustering object from scikit learn

    X     :  multidimension np array of data points

    Returns:
    -----------------------------------------
    BIC value
    """
    # assign centers and labels
    centers = [kmeans.cluster_centers_]
    labels  = kmeans.labels_
    #number of clusters
    m = kmeans.n_clusters
    # size of the clusters
    n = np.bincount(labels)
    #size of data set
    N, d = X.shape

    #compute variance for all clusters beforehand
    cl_var = (1.0 / (N - m) / d) * sum([sum(distance.cdist(X[np.where(labels == i)], [centers[0][i]], 'euclidean')**2) for i in range(m)])

    const_term = 0.5 * m * np.log(N) * (d+1)

    BIC = np.sum([n[i] * np.log(n[i]) -
               n[i] * np.log(N) -
             ((n[i] * d) / 2) * np.log(2*np.pi*cl_var) -
             ((n[i] - 1) * d/ 2) for i in range(m)]) - const_term

    return(BIC)



sns.set_style("ticks")
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette("Blues_r"))
bics = []
for n_clusters in range(2,50):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    kmeans.fit(dt_trans)

    labels = kmeans.labels_
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

    clusters = {}
    for i,d in enumerate(kmeans.labels_):
        if d not in clusters:
            clusters[d] = []
        clusters[d].append(dt_trans[i])

    bics.append(compute_bic(kmeans,dt_trans))#-bic(clusters.values(), centroids))

plt.plot(bics)
plt.ylabel("BIC score")
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.title("BIC scoring for K-means cell's behaviour")
sns.despine()
#plt.savefig('figures/K-means-BIC.pdf', format='pdf', dpi=330,bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Same problem here... What is K?

**Silhouette**

```
    from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

s = []
for n_clusters in range(2,30):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    kmeans.fit(dt_trans)

    labels = kmeans.labels_
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

    s.append(silhouette_score(dt_trans, labels, metric='euclidean'))

plt.plot(s)
plt.ylabel("Silouette")
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.title("Silouette for K-means cell's behaviour")
sns.despine()
```

[image]

Alleluja! Here it seems to make sense and this is what I expect. But why is this different from the others?

Comment: To answer your question about the knee in the variance case, it looks like it's around 6 or 7, you can imagine it as the break point between two linear approximating segments to the curve . The shape of the graph is not unusual, % variance will often asymptotically approach 100%. I'd put k in your BIC graph as a little lower , around 5.

Comment: but I should have (more or less) the same results in all the methods, right?

Comment: I don't think I know enough to say. I doubt very much that  the three methods are mathematically equivalent with all data, otherwise they wouldn't exist as distinct techniques, so the comparative results are data dependent. Two of the methods give numbers of clusters that are close, the third is higher but not enormously so. Do you have a priori information about the true number of clusters ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I expect to have from 8 to 10 clusters

Comment: Such plots arise often when the data has not been preprocessed well enough. Make sure to validate your results to not depend on a single variable only or to have degenerated in any other way (e.g. due to outliers)

Comment: You are already in the black-hole of "Curse of Dimensionality". Nothings works before a dimensionality reduction.

Comment: I'd second that, try using PCA first. Then apply a k-means afterwards.

Comment: Regarding the Silhouette vs k plot: How did you plot for 0 and 1 values of k if silhouette can't resolve that (and moreover, you are looping from 2)? You need Silhouette as close as possible to 1 to assume a good clustering. Your clustering doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Is it possible to share dt_trans for clarity

Comment: Another (simpler) solution to find the elbow point, or point of maximum curvature, to detect the number of clusters, is proposed in my article, [see here](https://dsc.news/2EYkh3E).

Answer (score 7):

Just posting a summary of above comments and some more thoughts so that this question is removed from "unanswered questions".

Image_doctor's comment is right that these graphs are typical for k-means. (I am not familiar with the "Silhouette" measure though.) The in-cluster variance is expected to go down continuously with increasing k. The elbow is where the curve bends the most. (Maybe think "2nd derivative" if you want something mathematical.)

Generally, it is best to pick k using the final task. Do not use statistical measures of your cluster to make your decision but use the end-to-end performance of your system to guide your choices. Only use the statistics as a starting point.

Answer (score 7):

Finding the elbow can be made more easier by computing the angles between the consecutive segments.

Replace your:

```
kIdx = 10-1
```

with:

```
seg_threshold = 0.95 #Set this to your desired target

#The angle between three points
def segments_gain(p1, v, p2):
    vp1 = np.linalg.norm(p1 - v)
    vp2 = np.linalg.norm(p2 - v)
    p1p2 = np.linalg.norm(p1 - p2)
    return np.arccos((vp1**2 + vp2**2 - p1p2**2) / (2 * vp1 * vp2)) / np.pi

#Normalize the data
criterion = np.array(avgWithinSS)
criterion = (criterion - criterion.min()) / (criterion.max() - criterion.min())

#Compute the angles
seg_gains = np.array([0, ] + [segments_gain(*
        [np.array([K[j], criterion[j]]) for j in range(i-1, i+2)]
    ) for i in range(len(K) - 2)] + [np.nan, ])

#Get the first index satisfying the threshold
kIdx = np.argmax(seg_gains > seg_threshold)
```

and you will see something like:
[image]

If you visualize the seg_gains, you will see something like this:
[image]

I hope you can find the tricky elbow now :)

Answer (score 4):

I created a Python [library](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed) that attempts to implement the [Kneedle algorithim](https://raghavan.usc.edu/papers/kneedle-simplex11.pdf) to detect the point of maximum curvature in functions like this.
It can be installed with `pip install kneed`.

Code and output for four different shapes of functions:

```
from kneed.data_generator import DataGenerator
from kneed.knee_locator import KneeLocator

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample x and y
x = np.arange(0,10)
y_convex_inc = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,40,100])
y_convex_dec = y_convex_inc[::-1]
y_concave_dec = 100 - y_convex_inc
y_concave_inc = 100 - y_convex_dec

# find the knee points
kn = KneeLocator(x, y_convex_inc, curve='convex', direction='increasing')
knee_yconvinc = kn.knee

kn = KneeLocator(x, y_convex_dec, curve='convex', direction='decreasing')
knee_yconvdec = kn.knee

kn = KneeLocator(x, y_concave_inc, curve='concave', direction='increasing')
knee_yconcinc = kn.knee

kn = KneeLocator(x, y_concave_dec, curve='concave', direction='decreasing')
knee_yconcdec = kn.knee

# plot
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10));
yconvinc = axes[0][0]
yconvdec = axes[0][1]
yconcinc = axes[1][0]
yconcdec = axes[1][1]

yconvinc.plot(x, y_convex_inc)
yconvinc.vlines(x=knee_yconvinc, ymin=0, ymax=100, linestyle='--')
yconvinc.set_title("curve='convex', direction='increasing'")

yconvdec.plot(x, y_convex_dec)
yconvdec.vlines(x=knee_yconvdec, ymin=0, ymax=100, linestyle='--')
yconvdec.set_title("curve='convex', direction='decreasing'")

yconcinc.plot(x, y_concave_inc)
yconcinc.vlines(x=knee_yconcinc, ymin=0, ymax=100, linestyle='--')
yconcinc.set_title("curve='concave', direction='increasing'")

yconcdec.plot(x, y_concave_dec)
yconcdec.vlines(x=knee_yconcdec, ymin=0, ymax=100, linestyle='--')
yconcdec.set_title("curve='concave', direction='decreasing'");
```

[image]